# How do I transpose rows into columns dynamically in SQL?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, dynamic-sql, transpose, rdbms

> To give you a brief summary—I would like to:
>  1. Join two tables both containing Address Book information, 
>  2. Concatenate the ‘phone number area code’ and ‘phone number’ (because they are stored in separate columns in our database) 
>  3. If the ‘Address Book #’ from Column 1 is repeated—have the information appear on the same row (see below for example).

Here are the tables and fields I am using:

**Fields in Table 1 (ABC_F0115):**

‘Address Book#’ 
‘Phone Type’
‘Phone Area Code’
“Phone Number’

**Fields in Table 2 (ABC_F0101):**

‘Address Book#’
‘Address Book Type’

My current SQL is:

```
SELECT WPAN8 'Address Book#', WPPHTP 'Phone Type', WPAR1 'Phone Area Code', WPPH1 'Phone Number', ABAT1 'Address Book concat('(',LTRIM(RTRIM(WPAR1)),')', ' ', WPPH1) AS 'Full Phone Number' FROM ABC.F0101 JOIN ABC.F0115 ON WPAN8=ABAN8 WHERE ABAT1='AR';
```

It returns a table similar to the one below:

---

|AddressBook#| PhoneType | PhoneAreaCode | Phone Number  |
|___________ _   _________ _ _____________   _  ___________|
|2160________| Cell______| 000__________| 000-0000_____ |

|2160________| Fax______ | 111__________| 111-1111______ |

|2161________| Cell______| 222__________| 222-2222_____ |

|2161________| Fax______ | 333__________| 333-3333_____ |

|2162________| Home____ | 444__________| 444-4444_____ |

---

However, I would like the returned table to look like:

---

|AddressBook#| PhoneType1 | Phone#1 | PhoneType2  | Phone#2 | PhoneType3 | Phone#3 |
|___________ _   _________ _ _______   _  _________ _ _________ _ _______ _ _______ |
|2160________| Cell_______| 000-0000| Fax _______ |111-1111_|___________|________|

|2161________| Cell_______| 222-2222| Fax _______ |333-3333 |___________|________|

|2163________| Home_____| 444-4444| Fax _______ |333-3333 |___________|________ |

---

I know I have to transpose my rows into columns dynamically... but I can't quite figure out my SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tag RDMS. No two SQL dialects are alike.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is something you are locking fore?

```
WITH Result AS (
    SELECT
        WPAN8,
        WPPHTP,
        WPPH1 'Phone Number',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WPAN8, ORDER BY WPPHTP,WPPH1) AS CallRowNumber
    FROM ABC.F0101
    JOIN ABC.F0115 ON WPAN8=ABAN8
    WHERE ABAT1='AR';
)
SELECT
    WPAN8 'Address Book#',
    Resutl1.WPPHTP AS 'Phone Type1',
    Resutl1.WPPH1 'Phone Number1',
    Resutl2.WPPHTP AS 'Phone Type2',
    Resutl2.WPPH1 'Phone Number2',
    Resutl3.WPPHTP AS 'Phone Type3',
    Resutl3.WPPH1 'Phone Number3',
FROM ABC.F0101
LEFT JOIN Result AS Resutl1 ON Resutl1.WPAN8=ABAN8 AND CallRowNumber = 1
LEFT JOIN Result AS Resutl2 ON Resutl2.WPAN8=ABAN8 AND CallRowNumber = 2
LEFT JOIN Result AS Resutl3 ON Resutl3.WPAN8=ABAN8 AND CallRowNumber = 3
```

Since I didn't know which SQL syntax you used, I did it with SQL Server (TSQL).